# Update ResultSet in MySQL for DateTime column

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I'm looking for the best way to update a DateTime field in MySQL while walking thru my result set.  I have found some other questions along these lines but none that addresses the Java data and SQL date formats within a rs.updateDate statement.  I have attached the code that the editor is balking at.

```
public class EmailQueueProcess {

    public static Boolean process()
        {

        Date processedDtm = new Date();
        java.util.Date today=new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp currentTimestamp=new Timestamp(today.getTime());

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            strSQL = "select * from portal.emailqueue where portal.emailqueue.processedDtm is null";
            conn = com.retailapppartners.Utils.staticGetConnection().getConnection();       
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            //now loop through and update the process datetime values
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
            // Grab some data then update the row   
                rs.updateDate ("processedDtm", currentTimestamp);
                rs.updateRow();

            }

        } catch .....
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you mean date "format"?

Comment: The Editor is saying:"The method updateDate(String, Date) in the type ResultSet is not applicable for the arguments (String, Timestamp)"  So it seems my variable is not compatible with the rs.updateDate.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center, and then edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson Compiler error. `java.sql.Timestamp` is not `java.sql.Date`, so you can't use `updateDate()` with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`updateDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.sql.Date%29) takes a `java.sql.Date`. So, I believe you have two options here,

1. Use [`rs.updateTimestamp("processedDtm", currentTimestamp);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateTimestamp%28java.lang.String,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29)
2. Use `java.sql.Date currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Date();`

Per the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) in Table 5.1,

```
These MySQL Data Types          - Can always be converted to these Java types
DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP - java.lang.String, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp
```

So you can use either 1 or 2 above.

Comment: the column type is DateTime ('2014-06-24 12:36:59') would rs.updateTimestamp be the correct way to go?

Comment: @RogerC Added documentation link, either way.